# Generating varying questions (Django Tutorial modification)

Tags: django

I would like to modify the tutorial poll that Django provided. I'm interested in varying the question displayed each time the user selects an answer. Specifically, pull questions randomly out from a .txt file, but keep the answer selection the same.

Can I use the model from the tutorial or do I have to create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi, welcome to SO.  You may wish to check this page... [How to ask
>   questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) - its best to ask a specific rather than general question here and show what you have tried to date.

Having said that this doesn't really sound like a job for django's model classes which are designed so that

> Each attribute of the model represents a database field.

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/)

You are best to use the existing poll tutorial model, but build a view which takes a text file and loads it into the database.  For instance something [like this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086630/django-import-csv-file-and-handle-clash-of-unique-values-correctly), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506678/in-django-how-do-i-select-100-random-records-from-the-database) may get you started.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to have a single, stagnant question, but I'm having a hard time generating different questions after a response. I'll dig around the site some more.

Comment: the last link shows hot to get random records... just redirect the user back to poll view showing a random poll